# JBPM User Interface - KIE Workbench vs Custom UI

Tags: java, jboss, jbpm, kie

I have built a process using JBPM. I am evaluating building forms using form builder provided by KIE Workbench. I saw that it uses Uberfire under the hood. What are the pros and cons of using KIE workbench for building forms vs using another are UI technology (angular js etc) and integrating that with JBPM process? Also is there a way to customize the form builder module to use other UI framework such as Angular JS , if needed?

Comment: Anybody? I also would like to do this..

Comment: Even I'm also looking for an answer for same.

Comment: Would you please share your findings in whatever decision and path you've gone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much of the functionality to add data items to Forms was removed in early jbpm 7.x including the ability to customise pages in an useful way. I'm not sure the reasoning for the removal of functionality it could be related to the migrations from the previous platform to uberfire etc.

It is so limiting now my project has struggled to even populate a listbox with data dynamically and chaining forms together is now impossible. We may have to end up building a custom front end - which kind of defeats the purpose of the no-code solution for workflow requirements. I'm not sure how this compares with the state of the commercial redhat product.